# How to simplify an expression with no constraints?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Simplifying expressions on Mathematica is a recurrent topic. However I found myself stuck with this one:

Solving an rational equation on Mathematica gives me the following expression:

```
expression := -((2 x)/3) + (2^(1/3) (3 - x^2))/(
  3 (9 x - 2 x^3 + Sqrt[4 (3 - x^2)^3 + (9 x - 2 x^3)^2])^(
   1/3)) - (9 x - 2 x^3 + Sqrt[4 (3 - x^2)^3 + (9 x - 2 x^3)^2])^(
  1/3)/(3 2^(1/3))
```

I know that the expression should simply to $-x$.
If I plot the expression I get indeed a plot of $y=-x$.

```
Plot[expression, {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Resulting plot]

I tried using the function "Simplify", "FullSimplify" even "Expand" and then "Simplify" but got no luck as I do not have restriction on $x$. The expression is very messy and I do not manage to simplify it by hand. How could I use mathematica to simplify "expression" to $-x$? (other than using a graphical plot)

Any idea are much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Try: `Plot[expression, {x, -10, 2}]` ?

Comment: How much do you trust magic? `In[348]:= First[GroebnerBasis[expression, x]]

Out[348]= x`

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the best or most general solution, but you can experiment a bit by Taylor expanding about $x=0$ to some sufficiently high order.

`Series[expression, {x, 0, 20}] // Simplify`

This results in `-x+O[x]^21` which means there are no corrections to $-x$ upto order 21 in the Taylor expansion about $x=0$. If this remains stable to even higher orders you have a probable guess as to what the result is.

Comment: As @Mariusz Iwaniuk points out the plot isn't a straight line for $x<-2$. This happens clearly because there are branch cuts at $x=\pm2$ from the $\sqrt{4-x^2}$ appearing in the expression. This is obviously not seen if you do a Taylor expansion about $x=0$.